# Applying several masks to an object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask

I've got a raster image (a photo of someone's face) on which I would like to apply two specific masks.

The photo is the following:

[image]

The masks I want to apply are like so (1st column is photo, 2nd column is photo and mask, and 3rd column is masked photo):

[image]

So that hopefully the face is fading in, while the torso is cut in the shape of an ellipse.

Unfortunately, when I try to apply both masks (`Object` -> `Mask` -> `Set`), the second always replaces the first:

[image]

I also cant use the union of both masks (`Path` -> `Union`), as it removes the blurring of the blurred mask.

So my question is how to apply several masks (with different blurs) to an object in Inkscape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply both objects at the same time, group them with <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, then set as mask.

If you want to apply them one after the other, apply the first mask, group the masked object by itself then apply the second.